# Poisson regression with offset - help with fit and visualization

Tags: r, biostatistics, poisson-regression, ggplot2, offset

My goal is to understand the relationship between the number of worms found in a plot of land and the percent silt that makes up the soil. The plots of land have been investigated to different extents (different exposures), which means some plots have more holes dug to measure the number of worms than other plots. There seems to be a general trend that more worms are found as percent silt increases.

I would like to do two things:

1. use the proper regression to better understand this relationship. I believe this requires a Poisson regression with an offset (perhaps a quasi-poisson or negative binomial regression?). The dependent variable would be 'worms' (a count of worms found in each plot of land). The independent variable would be 'percent_silt' (the percent silt of each plot of land). The offset would be 'holes' (the number of holes dug in each plot of land).
2. visualize this in a plot that has the rate (essentially 'worms'/'holes') as the y-axis and 'percent_silt' as the x-axis. Ideally, this would be done in ggplot with stat_smooth.

Thus far, I have tried modeling this with the rate ('worms_per_hole' = 'worms'/'holes') directly input as the dependent variable (model1), but I understand this to be incorrect because it is not count data. I have also modeled this with an offset (model2). The plot of model1 (see below) is essentially what I would like to have in the end, but it needs to be based on model2... I hope that is clear. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: After more investigation, it seems that I am able to include the offset in terms of a weight, which gives me identical results (see model2 and model3). This is much easier to plot.

Edit 2: Apparently this dataset is better suited to a quasi-Poisson or negative binomial regression due to the overdispersion.

**dataset**:

```r
df <- structure(list(worms = c(2413, 678, 653, 610, 276, 121, 109,
104, 98, 93, 85, 83, 66, 60, 55, 45, 33, 26, 23, 23, 22, 20,
17, 17, 14, 14, 13, 13, 12, 12, 11, 11, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 6, 4,
4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1), holes = c(609, 480, 284, 122, 228, 80, 74, 86, 48,
42, 137, 146, 106, 17, 30, 61, 87, 23, 39, 20, 7, 6, 78, 46,
12, 13, 7, 110, 4, 6, 15, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 5, 12, 32, 9, 5,
5, 9, 5, 3, 11, 12, 10, 10, 3, 12, 2, 4, 4, 5, 8, 4, 9, 4, 11,
9, 2), worms_per_hole = c(3.96, 1.41, 2.3, 5, 1.21, 1.51, 1.47, 
1.21, 2.04, 2.21, 0.62, 0.57, 0.62, 3.53, 1.83, 0.74, 0.38, 1.13, 
0.59, 1.15, 3.14, 3.33, 0.22, 0.37, 1.17, 1.08, 1.86, 0.12, 3, 
2, 0.73, 1.1, 1.8, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 0.78, 1.2, 0.33, 0.12, 0.44, 
0.8, 0.6, 0.33, 0.6, 1, 0.27, 0.25, 0.3, 0.2, 0.67, 0.17, 1, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.25, 0.25, 0.11, 0.25, 0.09, 0.11, 0.5), 
percent_silt = c(0.33, 
0.26, 0.48, 0.84, 0.13, 0.46, 0.31, 0.1, 0.35, 0.96, 0.15, 0.4, 
0.33, 0.66, 0.54, 0.34, 0.5, 0.47, 0.42, 0.53, 0.58, 0.11, 0.19, 
0.31, 0.68, 0.44, 0.14, 0.11, 0.54, 0.28, 0.31, 0.67, 0.32, 0.55, 
0.36, 0.29, 0.28, 0.11, 0.22, 0.16, 0.36, 0.16, 0.06, 0.13, 0.4, 
0.11, 0.53, 0.34, 0.36, 0.04, 0.17, 0.6, 0.19, 0.34, 0.12, 0.5, 
0.41, 0.3, 0.31, 0.12, 0.09, 0.32, 0.34)), class = "data.frame", 
   row.names = c(NA, -63L))e
```

**model1**:

```r
model1 <- glm(worms_per_hole ~ percent_silt, family = "poisson", 
              data = df)
summary(model1)
```

**model1 output**:

```r
Call:
glm(formula = worms_per_hole ~ percent_silt, family = "poisson", 
    data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.4796  -0.6700  -0.2660   0.4773   2.2720  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)   -0.5574     0.2565  -2.173  0.02980 * 
percent_silt   1.7648     0.5455   3.235  0.00121 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 51.797  on 62  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 42.128  on 61  degrees of freedom
AIC: Inf

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

**model1 plot**:

```r
ggplot(data = df, aes(y=worms_per_hole , x=percent_silt)) +
  geom_point(stat="identity") +
  stat_smooth(method = "glm", formula = y ~ x, 
  method.args = list(family = "poisson"), size = 1)
```

[image: Model 1 Plot]

**model2 - using an offset:**

```r
model2 <- glm(worms ~ percent_silt + offset(log(holes)),
              family = "poisson", data = df)
summary(model2)
```

**model2 output**:

```r
Call:
glm(formula = worms ~ percent_silt + offset(log(holes)), 
    family = "poisson", 
    data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-14.401   -4.569   -2.681   -0.413   36.054  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.02062    0.02767   0.745    0.456    
percent_silt  1.57681    0.06161  25.594   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 3502.1  on 62  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2919.0  on 61  degrees of freedom
AIC: 3198.2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

**model3 - using a weight:**

```r
model3 <- glm(worms/holes ~ percent_silt, family="poisson", data=df, 
              weights=holes)
summary(model3)
```

**model3 output**:

```r
Call:
glm(formula = worms/holes ~ percent_silt, family = "poisson", 
    data = df, weights = holes)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-14.401   -4.569   -2.681   -0.413   36.054  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.02062    0.02767   0.745    0.456    
percent_silt  1.57681    0.06161  25.594   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 3502.1  on 62  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2919.0  on 61  degrees of freedom
AIC: Inf

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

**model3 plot**:

```r
ggplot(data = df, aes(y=worms/holes , x=percent_silt, weight=holes)) +
  geom_point(stat="identity") +
  stat_smooth(method = "glm", formula = y ~ x, method.args = 
  list(family = "poisson"), size = 1)
```

[image]